# How does one wire CUPS to accept print jobs via TCP/IP at 9100 and pass through to pdf-cups?

Tags: print-server, cups, pdf

- OS FreeBSD-12.1
- CUPS-2.3.3

My goal is to get CUPS to listen for TCP/IP connections on 9100, or any arbitrary ip address and tcp port for that matter, passing the incoming RAW spool file to the `cups-pdf` filter.  After which a `cron` job or listener process transfers the resulting files to a WebDAV resource for access.

I would like to accomplish the pdf conversion task entirely within CUPS.  I have looked at `netcat` and `socat` and these may be where I end up.  But if it is at all possible to accomplish this with CUPS then I would like to know exactly how one configures a CUPS service to listen on a specific IP address and port; and to route what arrives on that TCP socket to a specific printer.

Is this possible?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use CUPS for this specific problem.  I ended up using a combination of `socat` and `gpcl6`.

```
export HPNP=4179 ; socat TCP4-LISTEN:4179,bind=192.168.216.179,fork,reuseaddr,su=hp3000 SYSTEM:'gpcl6 -dNOSAFE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/var/spool/hp3000/np${HPNP}/HP3000-RPT-$(date -Iseconds).pdf -' &
```

`socat` takes the connection and passes it to `gpcl6` via stdin ( - ). `gpcl6` uses the `pdfwrite` printer to process the output file.  The pdf output file is named with a source tag (external) plus a dynamic timestamp.

On the legacy host define a network printer to spool to 192.168.216.179:9100.  Send the spool files to convert to pdf to that printer.

Each print job creates its own pdf. The timestamp prevents filename collisions.  The gpcl6 -dNOSAFE option is required to allow gpcl6 to write to a file.

I further extended this to provide for PCL3 form overlays and multiple pdfs per spool file.  An exmple of this is:

```
export HPNP=4178 ; socat TCP4-LISTEN:4178,bind=192.168.216.179,fork,reuseaddr,su=hp3000 SYSTEM:'sed -r "1s/^.{42}//" | cat /var/spool/hp3000/forms/hll_inv_ljiii_85.ovl - | gpcl6 -dNOSAFE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/var/spool/hp3000/np${HPNP}/HP3000-INV-$(date -Iseconds)-%03u.pdf -' &
```

In this example the PCL3 overlay file is picked up by `cat` which prepends it to the spooled data stream and passes that to `gpcl6`.  The `-sOutputFile` option of `gpcl6` contains a `printf` format string (***%03u***) which triggers `gpcl6` to break the incoming spool file into individual pdf files at each page break.  Depending upon the spool file there may one or two artifacts, a blank sheet or a blank copy of the overlay form, created in addition to the actual documents.

The `sed` command strips off leading PCL commands created by the generating host,